# With maven, Rest calls return 415 response code

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I get the following error when I try to run my test after migrating project into Maven build.
Tests work just fine with identical code with normal build paths without Maven.

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.util.Vector, and Java type java.util.Vector<Stuff>, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

My test scenario:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    try {
        System.out.println(makeHttpRequest(new URL("http://localhost:8080/json/process"), "[]", DEFAULT_TIMEOUTS));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

makeHttpRequest:

```
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url, String body, int timeout) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    String response = null;

    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        bytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
        conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + bytes.length);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        os.write(bytes);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
        response = writer.toString();

        conn.disconnect();
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

JSONService:

```
@POST
@Path("/process")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Vector<Stuff> getLocations(Vector<Stuff> stuff) {
    return processor.process(stuff);
}
```

.classpath:

```
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.    debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jetty-all-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/trunk/server/thirdparty/lib/misc/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/trunk/server/thirdparty/lib/tomcat7/tomcat-jdbc.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/tomcat-juli-7.0.37.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Maven dependecies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Looks like a packaging problem to me. You're packaging this into a `war`? Can you check the scope of your Jackson/JSON-Simple dependencies and manually inspect the `war` contents to make sure they're getting included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency `jersey-json`. It should take care of the rest.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Explanation:
Maven handles the mandatory dependencies for you. You needn't think about which jars you need to add to have some library working. jersey-json is an optional dependency that adds type handler classes to the class path. Maven does not handle this kind of dependency for you as you may decide to use other packages.

Comment: Thank you. How does Maven dependencies differ from adding binaries to classpath? I'm completely new with Maven and still quite confused at times.

Comment: added some explanation